# How to remove shopping cart item after payment done?

Tags: shopping-cart, magento-1.8

I have clear shopping cart item after payment done. I have tried many code, but its redirect to empty shopping cart. I wouldn't like to redirect the page and remove cart items.

Thank you

Comment: add this question to http://magento.stackexchange.com/ you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

Or:

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->clear();
```

In order to redirect it on some page (e.g: success page):

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('/checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
```